# warning while declaring friend function in template

Tags: c++

couldn't find the reason why am I getting the following warning:

> ```
> simple_list.h:36:69: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream&
> operator<<(std::ostream&, const list<Elem>&)’ declares a non-template
> function [-Wnon-template-friend]    36 |     friend std::ostream
> &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const list &lt);
>       |                                                                     ^ simple_list.h:36:69: note: (if this is not what you intended, make
> sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after
> the function name here)
> ```

I have declared the friend function in the header file as shown below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<typename Elem>
struct Link {
  Link* succ;// successor (next) link
  Elem val;// the value
};

template<typename Elem>
class list {
  private:
    unsigned int lsize;
    Link<Elem>* first;
    Link<Elem>* last; // one beyond the last link
  public:
    class iterator;
    list();
    list &operator=(const list &obj);
    bool empty();
    unsigned int size();
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    iterator insert_after(iterator p, const Elem &v);
    iterator erase_after(iterator p);
   // void push_back(const Elem& v);
    void push_front(const Elem &v);
   // void pop_front();
   // void pop_back();
    Elem &front();
   // Elem& back();
    unsigned int max_size();
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const list &lt);
    ~list();
};
```

Comment: As the message said, you're declaring a non-template `operator<<`. How do you intend to define it? Out of the class definition?

Comment: yes I am defining outside the class

Comment: Are you defining it as a template `operator<<`? Then the `friend` declaration and the definition won't match.